# SAPUI5 - Get binding for multiple tables with the same id

Tags: binding, sapui5

I'm trying to implement filtering on a table. This involves the getBinding() function.

getBinding() works fine with a single table - id of "stock_table".

```
// update list binding
                var list = this.getView().byId("stock_table");
                var binding = list.getBinding("items");
```

However, when accessing multiple generated tables of the same Id, the getBinding() returns 'undefined'

How do I apply a filter to multiple tables with the same id?

Comment: The purpose of an Id is to be unique. How do you generate the tables?

Comment: We user 'row repeater' to generate the tables we need.

As you can see, each table will have the id of 'stock_table"

<c:RowRepeater numberOfRows="1000" rows="{stock>/ItemsByCategory}" id="groups_container" > <core:Fragment type="XML" fragmentName="com.rui-stockstales.create.view.fragments.ItemGroupTable"/> </c:RowRepeater>

<Table id="stock_table" itemPress="onOrderClicked" items="{path: 'stock>Items', templateShareable: true}" keyboardMode="Edit"> <columns>....

Comment: So every "row" in your RowRepeater is a "Table"? RowRepeater has been deprecated a few years ago btw.

Comment: You could try `const rr = this.byId("groups_container"); const aRows = rr.getRows();` and then loop at the rows (each row should be one table if I understood you correctly). For every row/table you access the binding and do your filtering. Then the table itself doesn't need an Id.

Comment: var n = this.getView().byId("groups_container") this has a bindingInfo of 'rows'.   I can then get the table list within the container with var rows = n.getBinding("rows");  This returns an array of oList. However this has no binding context, so I can't set the filter.

Comment: getRows() also returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was this...

Thanks for your help!

```
// Filter every table with the group container
                var oGroupContainer = this.getView().byId('groups_container');
                var oGroupItems = oGroupContainer.getRows();

                _.each(oGroupItems, function (oCategory) {
                     var content = oCategory.getAggregation("content");
                     var itemBinding = content[0].getBinding("items");
                     itemBinding.filter(aFilters);
                });
```